# JavaScript - If a function is passed as an argument, can it be returned as a string before the function is evaluated?

Tags: javascript, function, arguments, argument-passing

Consider the following code:

```
function add(a,b) { return a + b; }

function displayFunction(func) {
  console.log(_WHAT_SHOULD_GO_HERE_); // I want to log 'func' to the console
}

displayFunction(add(2,3)); // I want this to log "add(2,3)"
```

Is this even possible to do in JavaScript?

Comment: No, this isn't possible, because `displayFunction` only receives `5`.

Comment: @DenysSéguret I'm aware that JavaScript evaluates the function first, which is why I posed the question in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass as follows:

```
displayFunction("add(2,3)");
```

Now you can use `eval()` method to evaluate. I am not recommending to use `eval()` method but you can achieve using that.

```
function displayFunction(func) {
  console.log(func);   // return 'add(2,3)'
  console.log(eval(func));  // return 5
}
```

Comment: This fits best what I'm trying to do, and it's a simple and elegant answer. Totally forgot about eval. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The alternative is to pass the function and arguments as separate parameters and call the function after the log:

```
function add(a,b) { return a + b; }

function displayFunction(func) {       
    console.log(arguments);    
    func.apply(null, arguments[1]);    
}

displayFunction(add,[2,3]);
```

Comment: Ah, this is exactly what I was trying to figure out how to do, well done, I knew there was a way to call it and get the information.  Alternatively you can do  console.log(func.name+"("+func.arguments.join(",")+")") to have the string he's looking for.

Comment: @WakeskaterX I thought .arguments was deprecated though.

Comment: Oh, yeah totally is.  Still, the idea applies.  Replace the func.arguments with arguments[1] like he has above and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this would be to just log this yourself at the top of your function.

In your code, you could do something like this

```
this.add = function(a,b) { return a + b; }

function displayFunction(funcName) {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments,1);
    console.log("calling " + funcName + "(" + args + ")");
    console.log(this[funcName].apply(this,args));
}

displayFunction.call(this,"add",2,3);
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/29v2nrtt/1/

EDIT: I saw another answer in which they pass arguments in as an array, and my answer passes them in individually.. perhaps there could be justification for avoiding passing your arguments in as an array so I'll keep this answer in case it helps anyone.